# How to return JsonResult with HTTP Status Code 500 from Razor Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In my ASP.NET Core Razor Pages application, I sometimes send requests to the server via ajax.

In those cases, I want to return `JsonResult` either for success or for error.

But I can't find a way to change HTTP Status Code for `JsonResult`.

Here's my method:

```cs
public IActionResult OnPostFileUpload()
{
   try
   {
       // code to manage and save the file, this request is AJAX
       return new JsonResult("done");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       return new JsonResult(message); // how should I set it to be 500?
   }
}
```

Comment: Set `.StatusCode` on the `JsonResult` object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can assign the StatusCode to `JsonResult` as below:

```cs
using System.Net;
```

```cs
return new JsonResult(message)
{
    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
};
```

---

### References

[JsonResult class Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0#properties)